# Angular how to chekc if condition is met and show navbar

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

In my second ever angular project I have a navbar that I want to make it visible only after the user logs in and make it invisible if he logs in or is not loged in. In this navbar there is also the name of the user...

So what I managed to achieve so far is that upon login the users name is displayed in the navbar but only after I refresh the page. Upon logout the name stays in the navbar even tho I cleaned the local storage...

What I don't know how to do and am having trouble with is that I can't make the navbar not be shown on login page and after user logs in only then on al other subpages show the navbar. And whne loging out to hide the navbar again...

I hope I was clear on what my issue is and what I'm having problems with...

Here is my code (I have pasted only the code that is related to login and navbar):

HTML comonent tempalte:

```
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar *ngIf="currentUser" class="crm-main-toolbar">
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" class="menu-togle">
        <mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined" *ngIf="sidenav.opened">chevron_left</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined" *ngIf="!sidenav.opened">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <img src="/assets/icons/logo-white.svg" alt="" class="logo" fxShow.xs="false" routerLink="/dashboard"/>
      <img src="/assets/icons/logotype.svg" alt="" class="logo-mobile" fxHide.xs="false" fxHide.gt-xs="true" routerLink="/dashboard"/>
      <span class="toolbar-spacer"></span>
      <p *ngIf="currentUser" class="user-name" fxShow.xs="false">{{ currentUser.user_name}}</p>
      <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="userMenu" class="circle-button white user-menu">
        <i class="zwicon-user"></i>
      </button>
      <mat-menu #userMenu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/login">
          <mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined">account_circle</mat-icon>
          My profile
        </button>
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="logout()">
          <mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined">logout</mat-icon>
          Logout
        </button>
      </mat-menu>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <div id="content" [ngClass]="{'content-padding' : currentUser}">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

  </mat-sidenav-content>
```

here is the component.ts code:

```
export class MainNavComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{
  currentUser: User;
  currentUserSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.currentUserSubscription = this.authService.login().subscribe(user => {
      this.currentUser = user;
    })

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentUser = this.authService.getUser();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.currentUser = this.authService.getUser();
  }

  async logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
    await this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

}
```

here is the auth service code:

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  token = '';
  user: User;

  login(): Observable<User> {
    const params = new HttpParams().append('param', 'value');
    return this.http.get<User>(`${environment.apiUrl}azure` + location.search, {params}).pipe(
      tap((response: any) => {
        console.log('Response from login:', response);
        if (response && response.token) {
          localStorage.setItem('TOKEN_KEY', response.token);
          localStorage.setItem('username',response.user_name);
          localStorage.setItem('useremail',response.user_email);
          this.setAuthToken(response.token);
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return;
        }
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }

  isLogedIn() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('TOKEN_KEY');
    return !!token;
  }

  getUser() {
    const username = localStorage.getItem('username');
    const useremail = localStorage.getItem('useremail');
    const token = localStorage.getItem('TOKEN_KEY');

    let userModel = new UserModel();
    userModel.user_email = useremail;
    userModel.user_name = username;
    userModel.token = token;
    
    console.log(userModel);
    
    return userModel;
  }

  setAuthToken(token: string) {
    this.authToken = token;
  }

  getAuthToken(): string | null {
    return this.authToken;
  }

  logout() {
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
    localStorage.removeItem("TOKEN_KEY");
    localStorage.removeItem("username");
    localStorage.removeItem("useremail");
  }
}
```

Here is my user model.ts file code:

```
export interface User {
  token: string;
  user_email: string;
  user_name: string;
  validity: number;
}

export class UserModel {
  token:string;
  user_email: string;
  user_name: string;
  validity: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular's [ngIf directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf), that supports conditional structural changes, by checking for a boolean `isLoggedIn = true` for example entirely inline in HTML

This is your HTML code:

```
<mat-toolbar *ngIf="currentUser" class="crm-main-toolbar">
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" class="menu-togle">
    <mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined" *ngIf="sidenav.opened">chevron_left</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined" *ngIf="!sidenav.opened">menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
<!--Here I added the ngIf conditional statement to test-->
<p *ngIf="true">
  This should be visible for *ngIf="true", set true to false to hide
</p>
<!--Here testcode ends-->
  <img src="/assets/icons/logo-white.svg" alt="" class="logo" fxShow.xs="false" routerLink="/dashboard"/>
  <img src="/assets/icons/logotype.svg" alt="" class="logo-mobile" fxHide.xs="false" fxHide.gt-xs="true" routerLink="/dashboard"/>
  <span class="toolbar-spacer"></span>
  <p *ngIf="currentUser" class="user-name" fxShow.xs="false">{{ currentUser.user_name}}</p>
  <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="userMenu" class="circle-button white user-menu">
    <i class="zwicon-user"></i>
  </button>
  <mat-menu #userMenu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/login">
      <mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined">account_circle</mat-icon>
      My profile
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="logout()">
      <mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined">logout</mat-icon>
      Logout
    </button>
  </mat-menu>
</mat-toolbar>
<div id="content" [ngClass]="{'content-padding' : currentUser}">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: in the html template?

Comment: yes, in the documentation link that I provided there is multiple examples of several variations from simple to complex
  
  
`<div *ngIf="condition; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
  

<ng-template #thenBlock>Content to render when condition is true.</ng-template>
  

<ng-template #elseBlock>Content to render when condition is false.</ng-template>`
  

this is the shorthand form

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).